# Android Activity will not exit, onResume() is called immediately after onPause()

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, onpause

I seem to be running into a strange problem with an application that has two activities, both of which use mediaplayer:

I am creating an Android game. It has two activities: one for the menu (which launches on start-up) and one for the game (which launches when you select a level). 
I have it setup so that if you are in-game and then hit the back-button it returns to the menu activity. Then, ideally, if you hit the back-button again it should exit the application completely. It does not. I placed  `LogCat` debug statements in the menu activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods. I can see that `onResume()` is being called immediately after `onPause()`.
If I disable the music then it exits properly.

Below is my `onPause()` method for the menu activity. Am I not finishing the mediaplayer properly? Is there anything that would cause `onResume()` to be called?

`GlMainMenu` is my `GLSurfaceView`

```
protected void onPause() {
    GlMainMenu.onPauseCalled = true;
    GlMainMenu.mediaPlayer.release();
    GlMainMenu.hasPlayedStartMusic = false;

    if (isShowingPauseDialog) {
        pauseDialog.cancel();
    }

    super.onPause();
    MMglSurfaceView.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Some notes:

- If I launch the app, and press the back-button right away it works fine. It only fails if I launch the app, enter the game, return to the menu, and then try to use the back-button.
- using the Home button always exits properly.
- In-case it makes any difference, both activities are using `opengl` for graphics

Comment: can you override onBackPressed() on check the same?

Comment: Are you following standard Java naming conventions? Are `GlMainMenu` and `MMglSurfaceView` *classes*, or are they names of *instances*? Are you calling a bunch of public static methods, and accessing public static members? It's hard to read this code. Also, why are you calling `finish()` from inside `onPause()`? Have you taken some time to understand the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

Comment: onPause() does not exit an Acitivty, it puts it in the background, so Try using MMglSurfaceView.finish() instead of MMglSurfaceView.onPause()

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I think I found the error. When I was switching back from the game activity, I was accidentally creating multiple menu Activities. So the reason it was calling onResume() was to bring up the next menu activity from the queue, and the current activity was actually exiting correctly.